# angularjs error in IE8 "member not found"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer-8

I'm having trouble loading my angularjs page in IE8.  The page works in IE9+, Chrome, Firefox.

The console shows

```
Error: Member not found.
<div class=ng-scope ng-view>
```

The HTML of my ng-view is being rendered to the DOM, but angular tokens are not being processed: i.e.

```
<!-- ngView:  -->
<DIV class=ng-scope ng-view jQuery19103165109290058322="12">
  <DIV class="all pc ng-scope"><!-- ngInclude: 'modules/abc/views/headerBar.html' -->
    <DIV style="HEIGHT: 670px">
      <H1 id=title>{{model.ModelName}}</H1>

      ...etc...
```

(the above was copied from IE8 tools; it is not my source)
My source for the same section of the ng-view is:

```
<div class="all pc">
  <div ng-include="'modules/abc/views/headerBar.html'" ng-controller="headerController"></div>
  <div style="height:670px;">
    <h1 id="title">{{model.ModelName}}</h1>

    ...etc...
```

So my assumption is that a fatal error has occurred before tokens like `{{model.ModelName}}` are bound.

Having googled a bit, I have found many references to `"member not found"` errors in JQuery under various conditions, and some blogs about AngularJs under IE7 with a member not found error, but these are not applicable to my problem.

As far as I can see, my code should be IE8 compliant, as I have attempted to follow https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie and have avoided (as far as I can see) custom tags completely.

My angularJs version is v1.2.11
My JQuery version is v1.9.1

I note that angularJs v1.3+ and Jquery v2.0+ do not support IE8.

Comment: I know this won't be seen as a comment that contributes very much, but I would be seriously considering dropping support for IE8. You are looking to support a browser than is used by an average of 10% world-wide. jQuery made that move a while ago. I won't spend my time making it work when it's dropping like that. 80/20 rule should apply here

Comment: @user3036342 That's fine and I wholeheartedly agree with pushing users to upgrade.  My client unfortunately does not, and use IE8 internally.

Comment: OK, you are using appropriately old version of angular. Is also version of jQuery old enough?

Comment: @Ivo Peterka - updated - yes Jquery is 1.9.1; should be ok.